# onmouseover with a RoR linked image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, dom-events

I've got a button I created as an image. This button has a mouse over that switches to another image. Basic Javascript. I need the image inside a Rails link to. Is there a way for me to have the Javascript event inside the rails link?

**Here's what I have working:**

```
<%= link_to image_tag("../assets/images/buttonBig.png", :border=>0), :action => 
'signup', :controller => 'prelogin' %>
```

**Here's what I want:**

```
<%= link_to image_tag("../assets/images/buttonBig.png"
onmouseover="src='../assets/images/buttonBigHover.png'" 
onmouseout="src='../assets/images/buttonBig.png'", :border=>0), :action => 
'signup', :controller => 'prelogin' %>
```

Comment: Why do you want to do it that way? For starters I'd use CSS for this, much simpler and more robust. And if not CSS, mixing bits of JS inside HTML can get painful.

Comment: I don't prefer one way over the other. I'm new to rails and not sure what the correct way would be to go about doing something like this. I'm not using CSS because of gradient issues in IE.

Comment: CSS and JS are both equally susceptible to gradient issues in IE. You can avoid any potential issues by using a gif if needed

Answer (score 0):

Ok well this is best solved by not using Rails. You should stay strictly CSS here iwth something like this :

```
<%= link_to image_tag("../assets/images/buttonBig.png"), :action => 'signup', :controller => 'prelogin', :class => "button-class" %>
```

Write the rest in CSS :

```
.button-class {
  border: 0;
  background: url('../assets/images/button.png') no-repeat 0 0px;
}
.button-class:hover {
   background: url('../assets/images/button.png') no-repeat 0 20px;
}
```

Now note how I'm using the same image for your button here. The reason being that your browser only has to load one image. And the difference in states is the difference in background-position of that image. So you would slice your button to have both states available in one image. Then measure the pixel difference and set those coordinates after the `no-repeat` attribute I wrote above. In my example, I'm guessing `20px` y-coordinate difference.

Answer (score 0):

With css it's simpler and more robust, you must have a sprite instead 2 images:

1º You must create a sprite with `buttonBig.png` and `buttonBigHover.png` in http://csssprites.com/

2º Now you have apply a class to your link, sth like:

in your view.html.erb

```
<%= link_to image_tag("buttonBig.png", :border=>0), :action => 
'signup', :controller => 'prelogin', :class => "button" %>
```

3º http://csssprites.com/ will generate a values for `background-position` property: you must copy this values for your css sth like:

In your prelogin.scss file:

```
a.button {
       background: url("buttonBig.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
          }

a.button:hover {
           background: url("buttonBig.png") no-repeat scroll 0 50px transparent;
              }
```

In `a.button:hover` you can observe that the background-position is `0 50px`. you must check what value is correct for your sprite.

Regards!

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
<%= link_to(image_tag('/assets/images/buttonBig.png', onmouseover: "this.src='/assets/images/buttonBigHover.png';", onmouseout: "this.src='/assets/images/buttonBig.png';", :border=>0), :action => 
                'signup', :controller => 'prelogin') %>
```